# How to publish additional artifact with sbt (one-jar)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.1, onejar

I am new to scala and sbt. I managed to create an executable jar with one-jar plugin.

I am trying to publish this additional (one-jar) artifact to artifactory, but I am not able to do that. Does anybody know how to do that?

I had a look at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html but I was not able to get it to work.

(play 2.1.2, sbt 0.12.3, scala 2.10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to build.sbt and it worked fine.

```
com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings
artifact in (Compile, oneJar) ~= { art =>
art.copy(`classifier` = Some("one-jar"))
}

addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, oneJar), oneJar)
```

and then

```
sbt publish
```

Published the jar to Artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with one-jar but here is an alternative : give [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) a try. Same principle but with an [existing option](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#publishing) to publish the jar.

Comment: thank you. I added into Build.scala:  `artifact in (Compile, oneJar) ~= { art =>
    art.copy(\`classifier\` = Some("one-jar"))
  }

  addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, oneJar), oneJar)`. But that didn't work. I placed it outside `play.Project(...).settings(...)`.Is that correct? Sorry, I am completely new to sbt